# If a stylesheet lives on another domain, are relatives path in it relative to its own domain?

Tags: html, css, fonts

For example I'm including Apple's *Myriad Set Pro* font

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.apple.com/wss/fonts/?family=Myriad+Set+Pro&v=1" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

and it's `@font-face` declarations use relative paths like

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Myriad Set Pro';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:100;
    src:local('â˜ºï¸Ž'), url("/wss/fonts/Myriad-Set-Pro/v1/myriad-set-pro_ultralight.woff") format("woff"), url("/wss/fonts/Myriad-Set-Pro/v1/myriad-set-pro_ultralight.ttf") format("truetype");
    /* Copyright (c) 1992 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All Rights Reserved. Myriad is a trademark of Adobe Systems Incorporated. */
}
```

and I'm wondering whether those relative paths are the reason my fonts ain't renderin' on my site.

Answer (score 0):

The path assumes you have that wss folder in your base directory. When it's called it may be attaching that relative url to an absolute base url depending on where you keep your css files or your server settings.

Answer (score 0):

The relative paths are not a problem because they take from their main website (Here THe Apple Website).

But webfonts won't work on some browsers if just a .ttf and .woff file is assigned for the font-face.

It is a browser compatibility issue here.

To have a web font works in all modern browsers, you should have 4 versions:

.ttf, .woff, .svg, .eot

Example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'hacen_promoter_ltregular';
    src: url('hacen_promoter_lt.eot');
    src: url('hacen_promoter_lt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('hacen_promoter_lt.woff') format('woff'),
         url('hacen_promoter_lt.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('hacen_promoter_lt.svg#hacen_promoter_ltregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the relative paths within a CSS file are relative to the file itself, not the page linking to it.

I wasn't aware of Apple hosting fonts for developers. I believe that they do so for Apple apps. Where did you get the link to that file? Because they could potentially be blocking external sites from using it. When I tried to include it in a webpage, I got a "404 page not found" response:

[404 Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIylF.jpg)

There are also some alternatives to using Myriad Pro referenced in this question:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/350/web-safe-alternative-to-myriad-pro-font

Google Fonts are always a great resource, or Font Squirrel for commercial-free fonts that you can use on the web.

EDIT: Linked wrong discussion for alternatives.